# Dereferenced pointer cannot be used as the object it points to?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, dereference

I'm asking this because I got a compile error when I tried to compile this:

```
*string3.find('h');
```

The error I got was

```
error: request for member 'find' in 'string3', which is of pointer type 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
```

I thought this would work because *string3 is a string and the `*` operator dereferences the pointer so that I'm working with the actual string. Do class functions not work this way in C++ in general?

Note: I know I probably don't need pointers for this. It's just one of my professor's specifications for the assignment this snippet is from.

Comment: . has higher priority than *

Comment: what is the declaration of `string3`? if its `std::string` then you don't need to dereference it

Comment: [Operator Precedence in C and C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

Comment: You can parenthesize `(*string3).find('h');` or use `string3->find('h');`

Comment: How the compiler sees what you wrote: `*(string3.find('h'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have taken a look at C++ [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence):

```
std::string string2 = "hello";
std::string* string3 = &string2;
(*string3).find('h');
```

The reason why the extra pair of parenthesis is needed is because the "*Element selection by reference*" (i.e. your `.` character) has higher priority compared to "*Indirection (dereference)*" (i.e. your `*` character).

As your compiler hints, this could also have worked:

```
string3->find('h');
```

---

As a small debugging help: the error message you got says exactly what you need to know to solve your issue

> error: request for member 'find' in 'string3', which is of pointer
>   type 'std::string* [...]

i.e. "*you requested the member 'find' on a pointer object, how am I supposed to interpret this? This doesn't look right to me*"

Answer (score 5):

Use :

```
string3->find('h');
```

OR

```
(*string3).find('h');
```

`.` has [higher](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) precedence over  `*`